# Turn Off Delve But Not Office Graph

Tags: office-365, office-graph, delve

In O365 is there a way to turn off Delve but not Office Graph?  We want the collection of data to remain active but not surface it to users through Delve until we are ready.  There seems to be integrations with other areas of Office 365 that are affected if we turn off Office Graph.

Answer (score 1):

No that's not possible. The only way to turn off delve is to disable Office graph. But once you disable it, you disable all functionality in Office 365 that is powered by the Office Graph, such as Delve and the Discover view in OneDrive for Business.

[image]

Reference - [Office Delve for Office 365 admins](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Office-Delve-for-Office-365-admins-54f87a42-15a4-44b4-9df0-d36287d9531b?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US#bkmk_effectofficegraphonoff)

Having said that, Delve is always security trimmed. You can only view documents to which you have access.